# WCF service runs inside VS, but not alone

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service console application.  When I run it from within Visual Studio, it opens its tcp port and I can use it from a web site running on the same server.  However, when I run the console app directly from a command prompt, it does not open the port.  I don't get any errors, but netstat does not show the port open and the web site errors on calls to the service.

The server is running Windows Server 2003 and Windows Firewall is off.

What piece of the WCF puzzle is missing when I run the console app outside of VS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a `ServiceHost`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx

Visual studio creates a host for you automatically when debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I had ServiceHost, but in checking to be sure of that, I noticed that the .Open() for it was missing.  Putting that in got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jimmy said, you need to host your WCF component before you can use it outside of Visual Studio.

One of the most common and more straightforward ways to host a WCF service is via IIS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this problem even if you're creating a `ServiceHost` inside your console app, then it sounds like you may need to launch your command prompt with elevated privileges (i.e. in Admin mode).